# ng-submit / ng-onclick only works first time

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui, angularjs-ng-click, ng-submit

submit / ng-onclick only works once the first time i click it.
I use the Ionic Framework (if this maybe helps someone) to create an app.

And im really new to this stuff...

**The JS**

```
.controller('CustomerCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {
    db.get($stateParams.customerId, function(err,doc) {
      $scope.customer = doc;
      //$scope.$apply();
    });

    $scope.doUpdate = function(customer) {
      db.put(customer, function(err, response) {
        if (!err) {
          console.log("Successfully Updated the Doc")
        }
        //$scope.formc.$setPristine(); // removes ng-dirty doesnt help
      });
    }

  })
```

**The HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="CustomerCtrl">
    <form name="formc" novalidate>    
        <div class="list">
          <label class="item item-input">
            <span class="input-label">Name</span>
            <input type="text" ng-model="customer.name">
          </label>
          <label class="item item-input">
            <span class="input-label">Adresse</span>
            <input type="text" ng-model="customer.address">
          </label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="button button-large" ng-click="doUpdate(customer)">
          Submit
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find an example in the angular api reference [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit). Does that help?

The basic idea (taken from the link above):
ngSubmit enables binding angular expressions to onsubmit events.

```
<form ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  Enter text and hit enter:
  <input type="text" ng-model="text" name="text" />
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
  <pre>list={{list}}</pre>
</form>
```

Comment: not really there they only have the ng-submit not in the button but in the form.. else i cant see a differnce and i also tested it still doesnt work..

Comment: Have a look here: http://plnkr.co/edit/DRmatwMb4GQa8HhaWVDp?p=preview It is also working with your approach. There must be something else wrong. Did you get any exceptions on the console? Open your page in chrome, press F12 to open the developer toolbar and make sure that the Console is open. Do you see any red errors? Or to help you better, change the plunker so we can reproduce your issue better. But perhaps the current plunker can already help you to track down your problem.